# Jquery Get Value Data From Table, If match show the textbox

Tags: jquery

I have an JS code that the function is to show Textbox if value first textbox match.
like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){
var myString = "<?php echo $num; ?>";
$('#secondinput').hide();

$("#firstinput").keyup(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().match(myString)) {
        $('#secondinput').show();
    } else {
        $('#secondinput').hide();
        $('#secondinput input[type="text"]').val("");
    }
});

});
```

Now I integrate it with database, so the var myString must based on table. If data on table match, then show the textbox. If not, do not show.

The PHP like this :

```
<?php
include ("includes/_db_.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_test");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $num = $data['status'];
}
?>
```

I have tried that code but no effect.
Demo  without integrated with database : http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/369/

Any advice ?

Comment: if($(this).val()===myString) looks simpler, but the fiddle works for me in Chrome

Comment: your are selecting all from the table and replacing it to $num... i don't think this is correct... $num will always have the last status value..

Comment: So what I can do that @bipen ?

Comment: Use it as array. It depends on what u r querying from DB

Comment: @IntervalGrid It depends on what you want to do. You want to use only one `num` or you want to check if it matches any `num` of your database? If you want just one, just add `WHERE` clause to your query. If you want to check all, return an `array` and check one by one your array values to match it. Tell us what do you want and we will give answers.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. It will be helpful for us to solve if you give more details.

Comment: Hi @DaGLiMiOuX, I want to check all data, so if there are in table, it will show the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work. I don't know if I forgot something, but seems that this should work:

```
//PHP

<?php
    include ("includes/_db_.php");
    $num = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_test");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        array_push($num, $data['status']);
    }
?>

//JAVASCRIPT

$(window).load(function(){
    var myString = <?php echo json_encode($num); ?>;
    // or
    var myString = new Array(<?php echo implode(',', $num); ?>);

    $('#secondinput').hide();

    $("#firstinput").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ($.inArray(value, myString) === -1) {
            $('#secondinput').hide();
            $('#secondinput input[type="text"]').val("");
        } else {
            $('#secondinput').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In my data example like this, status : 03630C005-A2XXXXXX, that worked, the textbox will show, but If I try to change separate status like this 03630C005-A2X55555, the textbox still appear whereas in my table thats no data status 03630C005-A2X55555

Comment: @IntervalGrid Also, I have an error in my answer, because you will get a bad string array in JavaScript, let me solve it. Your variable `myString` will have all content from your table, not an array.

Comment: I tried your updated code. But it just want to show the textbox with the last data in my table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30387/discussion-between-interval-grid-and-daglimioux)